# Setting iframe src from JS / jQuery gives DOMException:cross-origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm trying to set a iframe src (with a relative path) attribute with JS / jQuery and it throws DOMException. If I set the src attribute directly in the HTML this error isn't thrown, just when I set it by JS or jQuery. It's the same application so it doesn't have any sense for me, any suggestion?

Although an exception is thrown it works, but don't know why it gives the exception.

`VM45:21 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:8123" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at fix (eval at dj_eval (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:108:33), <anonymous>:21:8) at fix (eval at dj_eval (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:108:33), <anonymous>:23:5) at Object.dojo.html.getDocumentWindow (eval at dj_eval (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:108:33), <anonymous>:26:3) at Object.registerAllWindows (eval at dj_eval (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:108:33), <anonymous>:212:29) at Array.<anonymous> (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:259:9) at Object.dojo.hostenv.loaded (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:239:7) at Object.dojo.hostenv.callLoaded (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:295:14) at Object.dojo.hostenv.modulesLoaded (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:288:14) at dj_load_init (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:851:14)`

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Please [search your error](https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+DOMException:+Blocked+a+frame+with+origin+from+accessing+a+cross-origin+frame.+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan this is the iframe `<iframe id="frameFormExposicion" class="col-xl hidden"></iframe>`

Comment: @mplungjan Already read it, yesterday I was there all day. But it doesn't have any sense, it's the same application, same origin, same domain, and as I said if I put the src value directly in the html the exception isn't thrown

Comment: Try to upload it on a real web server without a port number

Comment: I'm using JBoss to deploy the application in local, not able to publish it in production until get rid of that exception, although it works but you know...

Answer (score 0):

Its a security feature built into your browser to stop the user from falling for scams where genuine pages are encapsulated within fake frames and then interrogated.

No way around it with iframes I'm afraid.

Comment: An iframe should be possible to load with a page from the same origin. It is more likely a restriction of localhost and port than anything else

Comment: As @mplungjan say, that feature doesn't have any sense if it's the same domain, and as pointed before, setting the src manually in the html don't throw the exception